# Redirect_to rails 4 - could not find by lecture id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes, nested-routes

My models

```
  class Course
       has_many :lessons, through: :chapters
end

class Lesson
  belongs_to :chapter
  has_one :course, through: :chapter
end

class User
  has_many :user_lessons
end

class UserLesson
   #fields: user_id, lesson_id, completed(boolean)  
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :lesson
end

class Chapter 
   has_many :lessons
   belongs_to :course
end
```

My UserLesson Controller:

```
 class UserLessonsController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :set_user_and_lesson
   def create
     @user_lesson = UserLession.create(user_id: @user.id, lession_id:    @lesson.id, completed: true)
if @user_lesson.save
  # redirect_to Course show action///// How can I redirect to that?
else
  # take the appropriate action
end
  end
 end
```

Basically what I want to to is to redirect_to the show action of the Course that has the lesson? (it is basically a go back to the whole list of lessons. Lessons are nested within Course) The problem is that could not find lecture id.

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"lectures", :id=>nil}    missing required keys: [:id]
```

Routes.rb

```
  resources :courses do 

      resources :lessons

  end

   resources :user_lessons
```

Links that send the data to create method

```
   <%= link_to 'Back to Lesson list', user_lessons_path(@user_lesson, user_lesson: {user_id: 'current_user.id', lesson_id: 'lesson.id'}), :method => :post, data: {confirm: 'are you sure?'} %>
```

Comment: what do your routes.rb look like? Also you might want to run "rake routes" to see the route names and what params they need, if any

Comment: resources :courses do 
      resources :lessons
  end

Comment: I edited the post with the routes rb.

Comment: that's outside of the question but just a fyi, I noticed you used "lession" in multiple place which I feel should be "lesson".

what about, redirect_to @lesson.course

Comment: I got this error undefined course method

Comment: I added an answer + edited ... I think you "lecture" relations should be "course" relations in your models, from what I'm seeing

Comment: Yes I edited mypost, my mistake I copy pasted the wrong models

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `id` in your `redirect_to` method:

```
redirect_to :controller=>'courses', :action => 'show', :id => @user_lesson.lesson.course.id
```

#### Update after your question edit:

Change this:

```
   <%= link_to 'Back to Lesson list', user_lessons_path(@user_lesson, user_lesson: {user_id: 'current_user.id', lesson_id: 'lesson.id'}), :method => :post, data: {confirm: 'are you sure?'} %>
```

to:

```
   <%= link_to 'Back to Lesson list', user_lessons_path(@user_lesson, user_lesson: {user_id: current_user.id, lesson_id: lesson.id}), :method => :post, data: {confirm: 'are you sure?'} %>
```

which is basically changing this:

```
user_lesson: {user_id: 'current_user.id', lesson_id: 'lesson.id'}
```

to:

```
user_lesson: {user_id: current_user.id, lesson_id: lesson.id}
```

see if that works.

Comment: I am actually redirecting to another controller: courses_controller.rb and the problem is that it does not find the course id as it is not passed.

Comment: right, so you need to pass the course_id to that controller.

Comment: undefined method `course' for nil:NilClass cant seem to understand why

Comment: you need: `@user_lesson.lesson.course.id`
this should work

Comment: I still have the message error. My guess is that the lecture_id is never passed to the controller UserLessons. I edited the post with the link that passes the data to the controller.

Comment: did you try my updated answer? I still see `   <%= link_to 'Back to Lesson list', user_lessons_path(@user_lesson, user_lesson: {user_id: 'current_user.id', lesson_id: 'lesson.id'}), :method => :post, data: {confirm: 'are you sure?'} %>
` in your code!

Comment: Do you have the project on github? Then, add me as a collaborator and I will take a look after cloning it. In that case, my github id is: rakibulislam

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect_to lessons_path(@user_lesson)
```

But you should define show action in your UserLessons controller.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:
modify lesson class

```
class Lesson
  belongs_to :chapter
  has_one :course, through: :chapter #changed from :lecture since it's nowhere in your model structure
end
```

then you can use

```
redirect_to @lesson.course
```

to redirect to a lesson's course

Hope I got this right :)

Edit: I see that you mentioned lecture in multiple occasions but it's nowhere to be found in what you provided.... so I'm assuming it's now Course ? :)

If that's the case... change this as well

```
class Chapter 
  has_many :lessons
  belongs_to :course # was lecture
end
```